# Multiple insert into from loop with check on existing field

Tags: php, mysqli

I have read lots of forum threads and unable to solve my problem.

I'm parsing an XML file in a foreach loop and then want the parsed content to be inserted in a database table.

All is working fine but I have a problem while Inserting in the database.
Here's the code to make it "understandable" :

```
// Create connection

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

    foreach ($articles->article as $article) {
        $article_title = $article->title;
        $article_alias = $article->alias;
        ...
        $all_articles .= "('DEFAULT','$article_title','$article_alias'),";
    }

$all_articles = rtrim($all_articles, ',');

$query = "INSERT INTO my_table (id,title, alias,) VALUES $all_articles";
```

My ID field is UNIQUE and Auto Increment.
What I want is to check if the alias field already exists, than update it or create new row.

I already checked ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE and REPLACE, but it doesn't fit my needs since it performs a duplicate check only on unique keys, or my alias field isn't and I can't change it.

Last thing I'm testing right now is to make a SELECT before INSERT INTO with a WHERE condition to look at my alias field.

Comment: What is this supposed to do `$article_alias = '$article_alias';`

Comment: It's not really like this in my code, copy error the right one is $article_alias = $article->alias;
I have many other fields and code and tried to make it more readable ^^

Comment: it would be better if people see, and therefore try and fix your _actual_ code. Apart from the devil often being in the detail, it stops people from being distracted by red herrings like this.

Comment: The rest of the code has no error and I was thinking that having the most important part would be easier to read ;-)

I'm not sur that the 170 other lines makes an difference here, my problem is really to test if my alias already exists in the DB and then import new rows ^^

Comment: I didn't say you had to paste all of it, but the relevant parts you do paste must be accurate, not substituting bits with code you aren't actually executing.

Comment: Ok thanks ADyson I just edit the post ^^
Do you have an idea for solving my problem though ? ;-)

Comment: using a SELECT to test for the existence of it beforehand, as you've already suggested, is probably the best idea, if you can't change the alias field to to have a UNIQUE constraint on it.

Comment: Thanks ADyson for your answer, the problem is since I'm out of the loop I can't check the alias field in my array without making a new loop....
Or I have to test inside my foreach loop,that makes a lot of server request cause I'll also have to make the insert into the loop as well...
I'm stuck !

Answer (score 0):

I want to ask you a question here, and, if you can answer it, then you'll find the answer by yourself of your own question: What will happen if:

1. `$article_title` or `$article_alias` contain, hm, let's say something like `"YMas's lazy programming skills"`?

Let me help you - an SQL syntax error, because on this line:

```
 $all_articles .= "('DEFAULT','$article_title','$article_alias'),";
```

you do not properly escape variables. Bingo, MySQL insert failed.

**Rule number 1:** ALWAYS, always properly handle your input data before `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` - i.e. either by using `PDO` and prepared statements (best), or by old-and-flawed `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function.

Comment: Thank you bodi0 for not helping, your comment is a very great contribution to My problem  ^^
Are you here for helping or juging people ?
My problem isn't escaping specials HTML chars or quotes, So the foreach code is only here for understanding My issue...
I have no problem inserting My fields in the DB, My problem is how to create or ifnot update sincères I can't use  ON Duplicate key upadte or Replace Into...

So I'm not saying I'm a PHP pro if So I wouldn't ask for help, but I'd rather get some instead of bé juged... So if you don't aim helping, please pass by....

Answer (score -2):

I solved it by using another joined table to be able to use ON DUPLICTAE KEY ENTRY on my alias field.

Thanks for those how helped !